# Catching a single step exception from VEH in x86 assembly

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, x86

I'm writing some 32-bit Windows assembly that will detect edits to my program.

I'm not really sure why, but using VEH to debug a checked address causes it to crash (there  is nothing against debugging yet, just memory edits), throwing an exception_single_step in the middle of my checking code. I'm not using breakpoints, I'm tracing accesses.

How can I "catch" it without attaching my own debugger? I may have implemented it wrongly but my makeshift exception handler does nothing when it is raised (`mov fs:[0], 0`, even, does not cause it to crash as one would expect).

Comment: *"using VEH to debug a checked address"* What does that mean? What is a checked address? And how are you using VEH? Are you throwing an exception, or catching one? I find this question very difficult to understand. Perhaps it would help if you posted some sample code.

Comment: Sorry, I agree it was unclear. My memory checker checks a range of addresses, say from 0 to 10. I'm using VEH to trace what accesses address 5, and it crashes because of the weird way I'm getting memory (it seems to crash if an access is a pop, e.g. `mov esp, cur_addr pop eax`). I want to catch the exception. Sorry if my debugging terms are unclear. I'm using Cheat Engine (add address manually, find what accesses). Other debuggers don't crash.